# Get all items from ListView and convert to string Javafx?

Tags: java, string, listview, javafx, netbeans-8

I have a ListView in my Netbeans 8.1 Javafx project, and I wish to retrieve all the items from  a ListView that have been added to that and have them in a String.
I do not just want the selected item in the ListView, I want every item.

Apologies that I have no attempt at code, as I really do not know how to go about this.
Thank you in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class (example is just copy and pasted from there).

```
 // Convert elements to strings and concatenate them, separated by commas
 String joined = listView.getItems().stream()
                       .map(Object::toString)
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, ListView does have a method called getItems(). You might want to start with that.

Comment: String list = new String();
list = listView.getItems(); This throws up the error "incompatible types: ObservableList cannot be converted to String"

Comment: @JustReflektor So what does it return? What have you tried to do with the thing it returns? Have you looked anywhere for any useful methods?

Answer (score 0):

By converting from a Observablelist to a List, I was easily able to convert it to a String to suit my needs.

```
List<String> numbers = listView.getItems();
String listString = String.join(", ", numbers);
```

Comment: "Converting" is not accurate. An `ObservableList` is already a `List`. (You could just have written `String listString = String.join(", ", listView.getItems());`). BTW if you have extra information that is useful in providing a solution, such as the fact you are dealing with a `ListView<String>`, you should include that in your question.